# Orbits of the action of $SL(n)$ over $\mathbb{P}(Sym(n))$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

Let's consider the action of the group $SL(n)$ in the projective space $\mathbb{P}(Sym(n))$  given by
$g A= g A g^{T}$. Here $SL(n)$ is the special linear group and $Sym(n)$ the vector space of symmetric $n\times n$ matrices.

I would like to prove that invertible matrices belong in only one orbit, equivalently that given two regular symetric matrices $A,  B$ there exists a matrix $g\in SL(n)$ such that $gA= \lambda B$ for some scalar $\lambda$.

Any hints or references in the direction of the proof I'm looking for?

Comment: Are these matrices with real entries or complex entries? For real matrices, your hypothesis does not hold

Comment: This also fails in the complex case. In particular, we can see that the action is rank-preserving, so symmetric matrices of distinct rank occupy distinct orbits.

Comment: If you consider only the invertible symmetric matrices, then [Takagi's factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_decomposition#Takagi's_factorization) is useful

Comment: Thanks Ben. I've edited the post, I consider only invertible symmetric matrices as you've said. Coefficients are over an arbitrary algebraically closed field. It seems that it should hold under this hypothesis... Isn't it?